# Сохранение форм при неудачной отправке

Tags: php

Как сохранить введенные данные в браузере при неудачной отправке в базу данных sql, ну или чтоб информация в форме не пропадала после обновления страницы?

Comment: Не слушайте их, используйте `localStorage` :) http://htmlbook.ru/html5/storage Работает на стороне клиента, как на этом сайте.

Answer (score 1):

В любом случае вариант один - это сохранение информации формы на стороне клиента.

Как вариант, можно использовать jQuery .keyup() в связке с localStorage/sessionStorage(на крайняк можно Cookie).

В примере ниже код с использованием localStorage и библиотеки jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var text = $('#text');
  if (localStorage.getItem('text')) text.val(localStorage.getItem('text'));
  text.keyup(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('text',text.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <input type="text" id="text" />

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого существует два варианта.

Более простой, но чуть менее удачный, называется Post/Redirect/Get - выводить данные сразу же по получении. То есть, при "неудачной отправке" просто выводим опять же форму, и в неё вводим полученные значения. 
после успешного добавления данных, делаем редирект на тот же урл.

пример

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  
    // обрабатываем полученные переменные.  
    // пишем в переменную $err ошибки

  } if (!$err) {
    save(); // сохраняем  редиректим
    Header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  
    exit;  
  }  
} 
// показываем страницу с формой.
// значения заполняем из $_POST
```

Второй - чуть более сложный, но более корректный с точки зрения юзабилити. 
Записываем полученные данные в сессию, туда же кладем сообщения об ошибке, делаем редирект, выводим заполненную форму и ошибки.

```
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  
    // обрабатываем полученные переменные.  
    // пишем в переменную $err ошибки
  } if ($err) {
    $_SESSION['err'] = $err;
    $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
  } else {
    save(); // сохраняем  редиректим
  }  
  Header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  
  exit;  
} 
if (isset($_SESSION['post'])) {
    $err = $_SESSION['err'];
    $post = $_SESSION['post'];
    unset ($_SESSION['err'], $_SESSION['post']);
}

// показываем страницу с формой.
// значения заполняем из $post
```

Comment: Эти два способа не борятся со следующим случаем. Пользователь начинает вводить данные и нажимает F5.

Comment: @KoVadim, Можно придумать много возможных случаев. В вопросе конкретно интересует ошибка в валидации данных. Я в своём проекте использовал редирект на страницу с формой. Стираются только пароли.

Comment: ТС написал явно "чтоб информация в форме не пропадала после обновления страницы"

Comment: а можете какую-нибудь ссылку с примером по второму способу предоставить? вроде как в поисковике искал везде все размыто написано

Answer (score 0):

Cookies. Делаем событие onKeyup на инпутах и т.д. Сразу записываем в cookies. При обновлении страницы проверяем есть ли кука с значением определенного инпута - если есть то значение инпута присваиваем значению из кука

Comment: интересный вариант. Только наверное `onBlur` лучше... Хотя это уже от проекта зависит... Но вариант ОЧЕНЬ интересный!